# How to Remove Blue Box Around App Icon in .NET MAUI Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, maui

I am creating a .NET MAUI Blazor application and I am trying to change the logo, I am able to change the SVG file to change the logo to mine. However, it doesn't matter what I try I can't get rid of the blue box around it.
[image]

I have tried:

1. Resizing the logo to be larger.
2. Search for that blue color in all the solution
3. Set the Icon in the Visual Studio Project
4. Try a PNG instead of an SVG

and none of them have worked. Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

Comment: Can you try to modify the relevant style of the application logo?

Comment: @Chaodeng what do you mean by the relevant style?

Answer (score 1):

Open YourProjectName.csproj and edit the icon section

```
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg">
      <Color>#512BD4</Color>
      <ForegroundFile>Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg</ForegroundFile>
    </MauiIcon>
```

Comment: This is just recoloring the box from blue to purple. Its a workaround if you happen to have a squared icon in a solid color, like the default logo.

Comment: According to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5162#ref-issue-1356727021 Microsoft moved this issue to the Backlog milestone end Aug 2022. This means that it is not going to be worked on for the coming release. They will reassess the backlog following the current release and consider this item at that time.

Comment: @MatiasMasso, the thread you posted now says that the issue is fixed. But I am still seeing the issue. I have my VS22 updated completely. Any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: Hi @Mounika, I used Image Asset Studio to load icons for all placeholders and it works now

Comment: Little web search says Image Asset Studio is for android. Can we use it for MAUI in visual studio too?